# UDP send performance in Node.js

Tags: node.js, udp, benchmarking

I am benchmarking a Java UDP client that continuously sends datagrams with a payload of 100 bytes as fast as it can. It was implemented using `java.nio.*`. Tests show that it's able to achieve a steady throughput of **220k datagrams per second**. I am not testing with a server; the client just sends the datagrams to some unused port on *localhost*.

I decided to run the same test in Node.js to compare both technologies and it was surprisingly sad to see that **Node.js performed 10 times slower than Java**. Let me walk you through my code.

First, I create a UDP socket using Node.js's [dgram module](https://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html):

```
var client = require('dgram').createSocket("udp4");
```

Then I create a function that sends a datagram using that socket:

```
function sendOne() {
    client.send(message, 0, message.length, SERVER_PORT, SERVER_ADDRESS, onSend);
}
```

The variable `message` is a buffer created from a string with a hundred characters when the application starts:

```
var message = new Buffer(/* string with 100 chars */);
```

The function `onSend` just increments a variable that holds how many datagrams were sent so far. Next I have a function that constantly calls `sendOne()` using [`setImmediate()`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setimmediate_callback_arg):

```
function sendForever() {
    sendOne();
    setImmediate(sendForever);
}
```

Initially I tried to use `process.nextTick(sendForever)` but I found out that it always puts itself at the tip of the event queue, even before IO events, as the docs [says](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback):

> It runs before any additional I/O events (including timers) fire in subsequent ticks of the event loop.

This prevents the *send* IO events from ever happening, as `nextTick` is constantly putting `sendForever` at the tip of the queue at every tick. The queue grows with unread IO events until it makes Node.js crash:

```
fish: Job 1, 'node client' terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)
```

On the other hand, `setImmediate` fires after I/O events callbacks, so that's why I'm using it.

I also create a timer that once every 1 second prints to the console how many datagrams were sent in the last second:

```
setInterval(printStats, 1000);
```

And finally I start sending:

```
sendForever();
```

Running on the same machine as the Java tests ran, Node.js achieved a steady throughput of **21k datagrams per second, ten times slower than Java**.

My first guess was to put two `sendOne`'s for every tick to see if it would double the throughput:

```
function sendForever() {
    send();
    send();  // second send
    setImmediate(sendForever);
}
```

But it didn't change the throughput whatsoever.

I have a repository available on GitHub with the complete code:

https://github.com/luciopaiva/udp-perf-js

Simply clone it to your machine, `cd` into the folder and run:

```
node client
```

I want to open a discussion about how this test could be improved in Node.js and if there's some way we can increase Node.js's throughput. Any ideas?

*P.S.: for those interested, here is the [Java part](https://github.com/luciopaiva/udp-perf-java).*

Comment: @mscdex a while loop would not help, as Node.js wouldn't be able to finish the current tick and also wouldn't be able to process queued IO events... the application would freeze.

Comment: I belive in this case it's crucial to investigate also the java code. The link to java code you provided in `P.S.` section does not work. Could you please update it ?

Comment: Hey @JanOsch, thanks for noticing it. I have inadvertently removed it from my public account. You can check it there now; it's back online.

Comment: What version of Node.js this was tested against?

Comment: @JrBenito I was using v0.12 - the most recent version at that time, almost a year ago.

Comment: Might it be related to the fact that `DatagramChannel` buffers the data before sending, reducing IO and therefore sending multiple packets at once? [DatagramChannel#send](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/DatagramChannel.html#send(java.nio.ByteBuffer,%20java.net.SocketAddress))

Comment: @rels: Java does not send multiple datagrams at once. The underlying buffer the documentation talks about is just a queue to decouple your application from the operating system. When the documentation says *"the remaining bytes in the given buffer are transmitted as a single datagram"*, it means your buffer, not the underlying one. The operating system actually dispatches your datagrams individually - you may easily verify that by looking at the data received by the remote peer. Node.js also

Comment: @LucioPaiva okay. Thought it was flushed to the kernel in batches with Java which would reduce IO between Java and the kernel and augment throughput which would have been an explanation because NodeJS flushes it straightly to the kernel.

Comment: @rels yes, this could explain the difference for sure. We'd have to test it by confirming that Node.js does not buffer before calling the system (and, by extent, confirm that the underlying buffer that the Java documentation refers to is actually Java's and not the OS's) and modify Node's source to add a buffer and see what happens. Please let me know if you run any tests on it. I'm not working on this problem anymore, but am still curious about what could be wrong.

Comment: @LucioPaiva unfortunately I don't have the time to try it out, but I was also curious about the why, because I faced the same kind of problems under TCP and I was really disappointed by the perf achieved.

Comment: @rels np, I let you know if I do.

Comment: For the records, I tried your code with node 4.4.6 and achieved basically same results.

Comment: Hmm, I was just wondering if a newer version would perform better. Thanks for sharing, @JrBenito

Comment: @LucioPaiva so what is the solution here? I need suggestion for making a realtime multi-player game server sending packets with udp protocol. Is Java a better option for this type of requirements?

Comment: @newguy go with Java or C++ if you want to handle thousands of simultaneous players. Async C++ was about 10% faster than Java in my tests. Of course if you're expecting hundreds instead of thousands, maybe you can stick to Node.js anyway. You should load test your server as soon as you start implementing it to see how much it can handle.

Comment: @LucioPaiva Thanks. I am looking for solution for hundreds of players in one room but they may be assigned to 100 different rooms. So there will be tens of thousands of simultaneous players but they are playing in different rooms.  Not sure if Node.js can handle this smoothly. I am more familiar with Java anyway but the frontend is using javascript I might also consider Node.js as an alternative if it fits.

Answer (score 2):

That test is overfly flawed. **UDP doesn't guarantee the delivery of anything and doesn't guarantee that it would give any error in case of error.**

Your application could send 1000k datagram/s at 1GB/s from the Java application, yet 90% of datagrams never reached the destination... the destination might not even be running.

**If you want to do any sort of UDP testing, you need two applications, one on each end. Send numbered datagrams 1, 2, 3... and check what's sent and what's received.** Note that UDP doesn't guarantee any ordering of messages.

Kernels manage the localhost network in special ways. There are huge buffers dedicated to it and higher limits, no traffic ever goes through any network cards or drivers. It's very different from sending packets for real.

Tests might seem somewhat okay when they're only done on localhost. Expect everything to fail miserably when it's going through any physical infrastructure for real.

```
PC1 <-----> switch <-----> PC2
```

Let's say, there are two computers in the same room linked by a switch. It would be no small feat to achieve 10k/s UDP datagrams on that simple setup, without loosing messages randomly.

And that's just two computers in the same room. It can be a lot worse on the Internet and long distance.

Comment: You are missing the point here. I am well aware of how UDP works and I'm neither interested if the receiving end is being able to handle the datagrams, nor if the network connection will be able to transmit them losslessly; that's why I explicitly said that datagrams are sent to some unused local port. This discussion is about how many datagrams per second applications are able to fire given the same external conditions (i.e., same hardware, same operating system, etc).

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is to make the performance test go faster, removing the `setImmediate` call and executing the next send once the first has completed i.e. in the `send` callback increased its performance to ~100k requests per second on my slowish laptop.

```
function send(socket, message) {
  socket.send(message, SERVER_PORT, (err) => {
    send(socket, message);
  });
}

const socket = require('dgram').createSocket('udp4');
const message = new Buffer('dsdsddsdsdsjkdshfsdkjfhdskjfhdskjfhdsfkjsdhfdskjfhdskjfhsdfkjdshfkjdshfkjdsfhdskjfhdskjfhdkj');
send(socket, message);
```

Comment: Also, for the number of CPU's, run above in a child_process.